# Multiple INSERT not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, insert

I have multiple If statements that if true, inserts data into the db. The Problem is that the 2nd one of the INSERT statements inserts it 4 times. How would i stop it from adding duplicates. Also the returned $_POST['tshirt'] contains only one value which is being inserted 4 times.

```
if(isset($_POST['distance'])) {
$dist = $_POST['distance'];
$sql="INSERT INTO sportevent_parameters.Distance(value, user_ref, event) VALUES ('$dist', '$id', '$event')";
}

mysql_query($sql, $con)
    or die("MySQL Error: ".mysql_error());
if(isset($_POST['tshirt'])) {
$tshrt = $_POST['tshirt'];
$sql="INSERT INTO sportevent_parameters.T_Shirt(value, user_ref, event) VALUES ('$tshrt', '$id', '$event') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE";
}

mysql_query($sql, $con)
    or die("MySQL Error: ".mysql_error());
if(isset($_POST['partnerid'])) {
$sql="INSERT INTO sportevent_parameters.Partner_ID(value, user_ref, event) VALUES ('$partnerid', '$id', '$event')";
}

mysql_query($sql, $con)
    or die("MySQL Error: ".mysql_error());
if(isset($_POST['racecategory'])) {
$sql="INSERT INTO sportevent_parameters.Race_Category(value, user_ref, event) VALUES ('$category', '$id', '$event')";
}

mysql_query($sql, $con)
    or die("MySQL Error: ".mysql_error());
```

What would cause it to insert multiple copies into the DB?

Comment: your code will send four queries to the server no matter what values you have in `$_POST`. This is because you have four `mysql_query()` statements in the wild (not enclosed in an `if` condition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, [*please sanitise your user input before using it directly in a query!!!*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) - also [read this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Secondly - the problem is that your calls to `mysql_query()` should be inside the `if` statements. With what you have done, `mysql_query()` is executed regardless, only the SQL statement itself is changed by the `if`. This means that if the first `if` condition is true, but all the others are false, the first statement will be executed 4 times.

Change your code to:

```
if (isset($_POST['distance'])) {
  $dist = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['distance']);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO sportevent_parameters.Distance(value, user_ref, event) VALUES ('$dist', '$id', '$event')";
  mysql_query($sql, $con)
    or die("MySQL Error: ".mysql_error()); 
}

// etc etc
```

Comment: Hi thank you. That helped me alot. And Yes i will fix those loose user fields :-P

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: The mysql_query's should be inside the if statements so it does not get called if the if is not called. I would also check the variables you are passing.

Multiple SQL statements in one query are not supported in PHP. You have to split up each SQL statement into separate queries to the database.

Link to PHP Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php